# confusion with Relationship of objects

Tags: sql, database, database-design, orm, entity-relationship

I have one situation given below :

Each student can enrolled into more than one class.
Each class can accommodate more than one student.

which of the following is possible answer :

```
(1) 1 to N
(2) M to N to 1
(3) M to N
(4) Anything else
```

if answer is (4) than which other answer is possible ......

any comments appreciable,

thnks in advance, Milan Mendpara

Comment: Did you not think that "1" in it be irrelevant for 2 conditions stating "more than one"?

Answer (score 1):

It's **M:N**.

Look at the problem from both entity's perspective to find the answer.

- Each `class` can have **many** `student` entities. So we have `1:M`.
- Each `student` can be enrolled in **many** `class`. So that's `1:M` as well.

In a normalized database you'd have `Class` and `Student` defined (minimally) like this:

`Class: Id, Name`

`Student: Id, FirstName, LastName`

If you add a foreign key on `Class` to `Student` you're only allowing each `Class` to have a single `Student`. If you put the foreign key on `Student` to `Class` you're only allowing each `Student` to take one `Class` at a time. The answer is to use an association table as **this is an M:N relationship**:

`StudentClass: StudentId, ClassId`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's number 3.

Multiple students (M) call enroll in multiple classes (N).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> 3 M to N

You need to define a table with fields `class_id` and `student_id` to store the relations.

Check out this article about `database normalization`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization